# Getting text all all links on a page.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, pageobjects

I am writing a test where I want to get all the options that are displayed in a menu. The HTML for the menu is as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu context-menu open" style="display: block; left: 421px; top: 352px;">
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="save;">Save</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="duplicate;">Duplicate</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="delete;">Delete</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

I m using page objects with Capybara to do my testing. Currently, I have this...

```
module PageObjects
  module SomePage
    class OtherPage < PageObject
      def menu_options
        @element.right_click
        options = @page.all('div.dropdown-menu li')
        menu_options = options.map{ |option| MenuOption.new(option)}
        return menu_options.map{|m| m.text}
      end
    end

    class MenuOption < PageObject
      def text
        @element.find('a').text
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This allows me to, in my test, call `other_page.menu` and get `["Save","Duplicate","Delete"]`. What I am hoping to do is get rid of the MenuOption class. Is there someway to write the `menu_options` method such that it will get the text from all the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the `menu_options` method:

1. Get all of the links instead of the list items.
2. Map the text of each element directly rather than mapping them to a MenuOption.

The method would be:

```
def menu_options
  @element.right_click
  options = @page.all('div.dropdown-menu li a')
  options.map{ |option| option.text }
end
```